# MySQL: mysqlcheck taking too much disk space to perform operations

Tags: mysql, database, mysqlcheck

Every saturday at 8am I've the following `sh` script which makes a maintenance on all my databases. I run a `mysqlcheck` with `--check`, `--optimize` and `--analyze`.

This is the script:

```
# check: checks table for integrity errors
mysqlcheck -u root -h mydbendpoint.com -p'mypass' --check --all-databases

# optimize: reorganizes physical storage of table and index data
mysqlcheck -u root -h mydbendpoint.com -p'mypass' --optimize --all-databases

# analyze: rebuild and optimize the performance of indexes
mysqlcheck -u root -h -h mydbendpoint.com -p'mypass' --analyze --all-databases
```

The thing is that when this `.sh` is running it takes **a lot** of disk space. Here's a screenshot of my Amazon RDS free disk space:

[image]

Which of the three comands is taking so much disk space to make those `mysqlchecks`? `--check`, `--optimize` or `--analyze`? Or the three of them?

I can't find anything about this on the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlcheck.html).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: --flush Flush each table after check. This is useful if you don't want to have the checked tables take up space in the caches after the check. | https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqlcheck/

Comment: @unixmiah That's MariaDB, I don't see the `flush` option on the MySQL documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlcheck.html

Comment: Why exactly is the correct syntax highlighting bad? I makes the comments look like comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the `--optimize` which uses all that space. It basically rebuilds all your tables to regain unused space (data that was deleted), if you've configured your server with [innodb_file_per_table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html)

This is rarely necessary, you can skip that.

That said, you really do this on *all your databases*? This should also not be necessary. I only have one database where I do a weekly check, and the purpose of this host is solely to verify that my backups work. Once a week a backup is restored on this host, then the mysqlcheck verifies that all tables work. And that's it. My boss would fire me, if I would do this on servers in production :)